# how to execute update query into sqlite for iphone

Tags: iphone

How to execute update query into the iphone.

Comment: What programming language? C, C++, Objective-C, Assembly? (If no programming language is given in a question I **always** assume Malbolge.)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for query,

```
sqlite3_stmt *selectStml=nil;
const char *sql_qry = "select * from tableName";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_qry, -1, &selectStml, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK){
    NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating update statement for store. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStml, 1, [[[aryRecord objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT );
```